# Grep for single and multiple occurrences of '[ ]'

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a C source header file:

```
const int my_2dim_array[1][2];
const int my_2dim_array2[2][3];
const int my_3dim_array1[3][4][5];  
const int my_3dim_array2[1][2][3];
const int x_array[3];
const int y_array[4];
```

How can I grep to find -

- 1-dim array variables only
- 2-dim array variables only
- 3-dim array variables only

A Separate command is fine.

I tried with

```
grep 'const ' header.h | grep '].*['
```

but then it gives `'Invalid regular expression'` error (for finding 2-dim arrays here)

Comment: all at once or by separate commands?

Comment: Not sure why I got -1 for valid question.

Answer (score 3):

To get only 1-dim arrays:

```
$ grep -E '[^]](\[[[:digit:]]+\]);' file.h
const int x_array[3];
const int y_array[4];
```

To get 2-D arrays only:

```
$ grep -E '[^]](\[[[:digit:]]+\]){2};' file.h
const int my_2dim_array[1][2];
const int my_2dim_array2[2][3];
```

To get 3-D arrays only:

```
$ grep -E '[^]](\[[[:digit:]]+\]){3};' file.h
const int my_3dim_array1[3][4][5];  
const int my_3dim_array2[1][2][3];
```

How the regex works:

- [^]]`matches any character except`]`.
- `(\[[[:digit:]]+\])` matches any dimension sequence: `[` followed by digits followed by `]`.  This expression is all inside parens, `(...)`, so that we can apply a repetition factor to the whole sequence.
- `{3}` is a repetition factor which is applied to the dimension sequence.
- `;` matches the final semicolon.

**Limitation:**  This c parser will allow many things not contemplated by this simple regex.

Comment: How about if some of the array varilables contain macro? 
const int my_var[CONST_INIT];  
I suppose that 'digit' must be changed with something?

Comment: In that case, change `digit` to `alnum`.

Comment: Sorry, I found out that some of variables has spaces inside brackets:
const int my_var[ CONSTANT_INIT ];
that is why it doesn't get picked up.  How to address space in the regex?

Comment: Replace `[[:digit:]]` with `[[:alnum:][:space:]]`.